Starting the Catalan recurrence at $1$ instead of $0$ leads to wrong result
I tried solving the Catalan recurrence using generating functions, indexing from $1$ instead of $0$. And this gave a result that is slightly off. I'd really appreciate help with why my method doesn't work.

We know the Catalan recurrence:
$$P(n) = \begin{cases}
1& n=1\\
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}P(k)P(n-k)& n\geq 2
\end{cases}$$
I'd like to solve this with the generating function approach. I choose to define the generating function starting at $1$. This makes sense because the recurrence above doesn't have a provision for $0$. So why not avoid it.
$$G(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty P(n)x^n\\
 = x + \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty P(n)x^n$$
Substituting the equation it satisfies for $n \geq 2$ from above we get:
$$G(x) = x + \sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} P(k).P(n-k)(x^k x^{n-k})$$
Based on the picture below, we can re-index the summation

$$G(x) = x + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{n=k+1}^\infty P(k) P(n-k) (x^k x^{n-k})$$
Now we substitute $j = n-k$ to get:
$$G(x) = x + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty P(k) P(j) (x^k x^{j})$$
And now the two summations can be separated to give:
$$G(x) = x + G(x)^2 \tag{1}$$

However, based on the Wikipedia article, the equation we were supposed to get:
$$G(x) = 1+x.G(x)^2$$
This is different from the equation I got and will lead to an off by one error. Where did I go wrong?

Nothing wrong here. You simply have $G_{\text{your}}(x)=x\ G_{\text{wiki}}(x)$. This, substituted into your $G_{\text{your}}(x)=x+G_{\text{your}}(x)^2$, after division by $x$, gives the expected $G_{\text{wiki}}(x)=1+x\ G_{\text{wiki}}(x)^2$.

Thanks. Why is it that the two generating functions don't contradict each other? Mine has a certain conclusion for $P(2)$ and the wiki one has another. Aren't the two different? How is this reconciled?

@RohitPandey You and Wikipedia are finding the generating functions for two different sequences, so you should get different functions and different values for $P(2)$. Wikipedia’s sequence is $(1,1,2,5,\dots)$, while your sequence is $(0,1,1,2,5,\dots)$.

@MikeEarnest - what's tripping me up is that I explicitly used the fact that $P(1)=1$ in my solution. How then can I get $P(1)=0$?

Actually, never mind. Just realized that the wikipedia one starts at $0$.
